# Craps chips variable not changing

Tags: java, loops

This is the code for a craps game and problem is that even though chips starts at a 100 it always be changing based on whether you win or lose. For example if you lose you will lose the amount you bet and you start the next game with the new amount.

The chips start at a 100 but I only want that in the first game. In the second game it should be a new value and that value should be chips you have currently plus/minus (based on if you win or lose) how much you bet. The problem that is no matter what game it is it always adds or subtracts from a 100.

What's going wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Crabs {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double chips = 100;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int dice = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
        int twelvetotal = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
        System.out.println("You have " + chips+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
        while(chips != 0){  
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            double bet = scan.nextDouble(); 
            while (bet > chips){
                if (chips == 0) break;
                System.out.println("Please put the amount of chips you have or lower. How much do you want to bet?");
                bet = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Type 'r' to roll the dices");
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            String roll = input.nextLine();
            while (!roll.equals("r")){
                System.out.println("Please press r");
                roll = input.nextLine();
            }
            dice = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice);
            double remainedwhenlost = chips - bet;
            double remainedwhenwin = chips + bet;

            if (dice == 2 || dice == 3 || dice == 12){
                System.out.println("You crapped out and lost "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("===================LOSER===================");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenlost+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                remainedwhenlost = chips;
            }
            else if (dice == 7 || dice == 11){
                System.out.println("YOU WON!!!! You got "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ WINNER $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenwin+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                remainedwhenwin = chips;
            }
            else
            do {
                twelvetotal = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
                System.out.println("Type 'r' to roll the dices");
                String MorethanoneRoll = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("You rolled a " + twelvetotal);
            }while(twelvetotal != dice && twelvetotal != 7);
            if (twelvetotal == dice){
                System.out.println("YOU WON!!!! You got "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ WINNER $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenwin+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                remainedwhenwin = chips;
            }
            else if (twelvetotal == 7){
                System.out.println("You crapped out and lost "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("===================LOSER===================");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenlost+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                remainedwhenlost = chips;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Game Over you ran out of chips.");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please point out line(s) of code that change the value of `chips`.

Comment: I think he got a problem with his scoring system, the question is not clear.

Comment: line 27, 28, 34, 40, 53, and 59

Comment: The chips start at a 100 but I only want that in the first game. In the second game it should be a new value and that value should be chips you have currently plus/minus (based on if you win or lose) how much you bet. The problem that is no matter what game it is it always adds or subtracts from a 100.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to inverse your assignations:

```
remainedwhenwin = chips;
```

to

```
chips = remainedwhenwin;
```

and

```
remainedwhenwin = chips;
```

to

```
chips = remainedwhenwin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value of the variable `chips`.

When you do things like this:

```
remainedwhenlost = chips;
```

You are changing the value of `remainedwhenlosst`, but `chips` stays with the initial `100` value.

The value of `remainedwhenwin` and `remainedwhenlost` is being lost at every iteration of the `while` loop. In other words, you are not saving the result of the loops.

Take a look:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;


public class Crabs {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double chips = 100;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int dice = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
        int twelvetotal = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
        System.out.println("You have " + chips+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");

        while(chips != 0) {  

            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            double bet = scan.nextDouble(); 

            while (bet > chips){
                if (chips == 0) break;
                System.out.println("Please put the amount of chips you have or lower. How much do you want to bet?");
                bet = scan.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Type 'r' to roll the dices");

            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            String roll = input.nextLine();

            while (!roll.equals("r")){
                System.out.println("Please press r");
                roll = input.nextLine();
            }

            dice = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice);
            double remainedwhenlost = chips - bet;
            double remainedwhenwin = chips + bet;

            if (dice == 2 || dice == 3 || dice == 12){
                System.out.println("You crapped out and lost "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("===================LOSER===================");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenlost+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                chips = remainedwhenlost;

            }

            else if (dice == 7 || dice == 11){
                System.out.println("YOU WON!!!! You got "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ WINNER $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenwin+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                chips = remainedwhenwin;

            } else {
                do {
                    twelvetotal = generator.nextInt((12 - 2)+1)+2;
                    System.out.println("Type 'r' to roll the dices");
                    String MorethanoneRoll = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("You rolled a " + twelvetotal);
                }while(twelvetotal != dice && twelvetotal != 7);
            }

            if (twelvetotal == dice){
                System.out.println("YOU WON!!!! You got "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ WINNER $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenwin+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                chips = remainedwhenwin;

            }

            else if (twelvetotal == 7){
                System.out.println("You crapped out and lost "+ bet +" chips.");
                System.out.println("===================LOSER===================");
                System.out.println("You have "+remainedwhenlost+ " chips. How many do you want to bet?");
                chips = remainedwhenlost;

            }
        }

        System.out.println("Game Over you ran out of chips.");
    }
}
```